# Docker unable to access ports other than port 80 on the host

Tags: powershell, docker, port

I have a situation where i have problems accessing my non-80 ports on host from docker. There is an application in my container needed to access this port 55555 on my host.

I have 2 VMs - VM1 and VM2. 
VM1 has dockers and a container running. VM2 is a machine that i used to do testing.

Command used to start the container

`docker run -dit --hostname VM1 --name ContainerTest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-20191008-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

I execute `exec -it XXXX powershell` to execute PowerShell scripts needed. I used `test-netconnection` to test my connections.

Problem:

1. I tried to run the following PowerShell script `test-netconnection -ComputerName "VM1" -port 55555` from my container - Failed.
   However, i can do run `test-netconnection -ComputerName "VM1" -port 80` and able to receive `TcpTestSucceeded`. All other ports that i tried failed too.

What have i tried:

1. I proved that VM1's port 55555 is opened to the public, as i can ping, and tcp test it from VM2 to VM1 successfully.
2. Turned off the firewall on VM1. No success either.

I am also aware that docker has `--expose and -p` command to expose the ports, however, in my case, i think i do not need to, as my goal is to access host's port from the container, not the other way.

I don't understand why is this port 55555 only accessible from VM2 to VM1, but not from container to VM1, and the container can access VM1 via port 80 only. Can anyone share some light on what is going on? Appreciate it.

Comment: `--hostname` becomes the hostname of your *container*; it is not an alias for the host machine. For that, use the built-in `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you elaborate the usage on host.docker.internal, i checked it is available from version v18.03 onwards, i am using v19+, however, i cannot `ping host.docker.internal` from my container, do i have explicitly include them in my `docker run` command ?

Comment: Are you on Linux, by any chance? Unfortunately `host.docker.internal` is supported only on Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac (Linux support is in the works but hasn't landed yet, see [the issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264) for suggested workarounds). If you *are* on Windows, can you see if `docker run -it alpine ping -c1 host.docker.internal` works?

Answer (score 0):

by the general there is a service that open the port not just port number
in docker you shoude use docker network driver overlay for docker use in other networks
hope link help you
https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: Link-only answers are not encouraged, please add some context to explain how this answer will solve the problem in question.